# Correct way to use fluent syntax in jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I write

```
$month.find('.d-row').attr('id', 'myid');
```

I don't get intellisense in Visual Studio for **.attr(...)** indicating that the syntax is not quite right.

if however I write :

```
$($month.find('.d-row')).attr('id', 'myid');
```

I get intellisense, indicating this is the correct way to write this

However, both syntaxes work fine, im assuming it is correct to use the second way, is this right & why do both work?

Comment: Intellisense can only go so far, it shouldn't be used to decide which way is better or even if syntax is correct. It is just a tool to help you along.

Comment: Yeah im seeing that now, it helps a little as im on the learning curve but I understand what your saying and the point being made is : don't trust the help, read the docs. Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way works because `$($some_jQuery_object)` just returns the same jQuery object, so no matter how many jQuery wrappers you slap around a DOM element, you get the same object.

That said, the first way is valid, correct, and preferable. Visual Studio clearly needs a bug fix.

Comment: Marking as answer because you gave answer first & you need a liitle 10K push :-)

Answer (score 6):

The second way is **not** more correct. It is equivalent to the first way, but **less efficient.** The second way is less efficient because it re-jQuerifies a jQuery object, which is completely unnecessary when you're already working with a jQuery object. To reiterate: if `$foo` is already a jQuery object, there is absolutely **no reason** to write `$($foo)`, ever.

They both work because they are equivalent.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the efficiency statement?

Comment: Thats exactly what I initially thought but VS intellisense threw me.